# Passing Data from one controller method to another in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a page that has 2 text boxes First Name and last Name after user click on sign up button API will run and returns user info and shows another page(view) that had user Phone, email,.. That fill with the info that API returns. I have 1 controller and 2 views.
I get the info from API and return the second view but not sure how fill the text boxes with the info I have. The problem is using the models in view, I have 2 models one for each view. I am getting this error when I call the second view:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type Models.CreateLogInRequest'.

This is my controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SearchUser()
    {           
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> SearchUser(UserSearchRequest userSearchRequest)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        object userObject = null;

        string baseUrl = "http://test/api/users";
        if (userSearchRequest.FirstName != null && userSearchRequest.LastName)
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync(string.Format("{0}{1}/{2}/{3}", baseUrl, "/users", userSearchRequest.FirstName, userSearchRequest.LastName));

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                userObject = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result) as object;
            }
        }
        if (userObject != null)
        {
            return View("Create", userObject);
        }
        return View("Create", null);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CreateLogInRequest createLogInRequest)
    {

        return View();
    }
```

This is my First View that shows 2 text boxes:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("SearchUser", "SignUp", FormMethod.Post))
   {
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" placeholder="First NAME" />
<input id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text" placeholder="LastName " />
<input id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="SIGN UP TODAY"     />
   }
```

and this is my model for 1st view:

```
 public class UserSearchRequest
  {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
  }
```

This is the second View:

```
   @model Models.CreateLogInRequest

   @{
  ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

 @using (Html.BeginForm("create", "SignUp", FormMethod.Post))
 {
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   <input id="Email" name="Email" type="text" placeholder="Email"   value="@Model.Email" />
   <input id="Phone" name="Phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone"    value="@Model.Phone" />
   <input id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="CREATE ACCOUNT" />
 }
```

and this is Model for this view:

```
public class CreateLogInRequest
  {
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
  ....
   }
```

Comment: The error message is useful.  You need to tell the `JavascriptSerializer` what `Type` you are deserialising.  There should be a generic version of the `Deserialize()` method.

Comment: I think you want to `return RedirectToAction('Create', userObject)` too.  Using `return View(...)` won't go to another controller method first.

Answer (score 0):

See my comments and try this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SearchUser()
{           
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> SearchUser(UserSearchRequest userSearchRequest)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    CreateLogInRequest userObject = null;

    string baseUrl = "http://test/api/users";

    if (userSearchRequest.FirstName != null && userSearchRequest.LastName)
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(string.Format("{0}{1}/{2}/{3}", baseUrl, "/users", userSearchRequest.FirstName, userSearchRequest.LastName));

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            userObject = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject<CreateLogInRequest>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        }
    }

    if (userObject != null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Create", userObject);
    }

    return View("Create", null);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateLogInRequest createLogInRequest)
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `Controller` you can create a new instance of `Models.CreateLogInRequest` model and fill the related properties received from 1st `View`. If `Models.CreateLogInRequest` does not contain such properties then it is better to load these values by using `TempData` or `ViewBag` in the `Controller` retrieved from the 1st View and pass them to the 2nd View. For the differences between ViewBag, ViewData, or TempData you might have a look at [When to use ViewBag, ViewData, or TempData in ASP.NET MVC 3 applications](http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp-net-mvc-3-applications/). Hope this helps...